# Export data from Python to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, export

I'm trying to export data from Python using (http://jupyter.org/) to Excel

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
df = pd.read_csv('rr.csv') 
df['COLLISION_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['COLLISION_DATE'],format='%Y%m%d')
df['week'], df['month'], df['year'],df['day'] = df['COLLISION_DATE'].dt.week, df['COLLISION_DATE'].dt.month, df['COLLISION_DATE'].dt.year,df['COLLISION_DATE'].dt.day
df = df.groupby('month').size().to_frame('Number of Accidents') 
df.plot.line()
plt.show()
df
df.to_excel('m.xlsx')
```

I'm getting error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: `No module named 'openpyxl'
```

this is my first project using Python Any Idea whats wrong or any other code that I can Use ?

Comment: you have to install it using `pip install openpyxl`, it's not provided by default

Comment: Is it possible to use online Python http://jupyter.org/ Or do I have to install it on my computer ?

Comment: I wouldn't know, sorry. but it's lightweight and very easy to install. shouldn't be a problem. Even if you're not sysadmin, you can put it in your pythonpath after downloading it.

Comment: @Ara No, the notebook at https://try.jupyter.org/ doesn't have the `openpyxl` module available. So you'll need to have the Python modules on your own computer. Download and install for example the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/download/). It has a user-friendly installer, and it already includes the `openpyxl`, `jupyter`, `pandas` and `matplotlib` modules right away.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Azure notebook (https://notebooks.azure.com) which is in an online Jupyter notebook. I tried one my DataFrame which I downloaded from Kaggle to export and seems it's working and below is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/home/nbuser/armenian_pubs.csv')
df.to_excel('data_set_2.xlsx')
```

Note that here you need to upload the any data set (CSV) file via Data > Upload menu from local system, then I used the DF to_excel of Panda method to create the Excel with just file name. This creates the file name on the `/library` folder and from there you can use Data > Download to download the file.

[image]

Hope this will help in your scenario.